# Convert float to string with comma and dot

Tags: c#, silverlight, floating-point

I have a nullable float. The internal decimal places can be separated with dot or comma e.g. 1.2 or 1,2. I need this float as a string to compare it to a Regex. If I use the Convert.toString method, the float with the comma is 12 and not 1.2. How can I convert a float to String without loosing the comma or the dot? I alredy tried to convert it with diffrent cultures.

Thanks for your help

Comment: and what should 1.200,00 be parsed as?

Comment: the float is a percentage so it can only takes values from 0,00 to 100,00 or 0.00 to 100.00

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the internal decimal places can be separated with dot or comma?"  A nullable float doesn't intrinsically care what the separator is: you can have "a string representation of a float that uses a comma as the decimal separator," but you can't have "a float with a comma."

Comment: The float is binding to a TextBox. In this Textbox you can separate write the float with comma and dot. And if I tried to convert this float to a string I loose the comma as a separator.

Comment: If you explained what you *want* to accomplish, rather than *how* you want to accomplish it, you might have better luck.

Comment: @Greg: In all fairness that way lies "I want a website that will make me lots of money. Can you tell me how to accomplish this?". I think its fair if people think they have the right way to do something to ask about that specific thing. For a start he *has* got a problem with covnerting his float to a string, no matter whether his regex is the right way to solve his base problem. So we can try to solve his problem *and* suggest alternatives to what he is doing.

Comment: @Chris: I see no slippery slope argument when asking to clarify a question with 4 answers, none with upvotes.  The question doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @Greg: Maybe you're right and I'm just thinking of it from a different point of view. My main thought is that there is a clear problem. He uses a convert.ToString on a float and gets 12 when he expects 1.2. We don't have enough info to debug this which is I think why we have no good answers. However, I think that just means we need more information on this question rather than necessarily the question being different. The more I think about it though the more I suspect we might well be thinking about the same thing and I just misunderstood your initial comment.

Answer (score 3):

A solution for this can be the following:

```
float? num = 1.2f;
string floatAsString = string.Format("{0:f}", num.Value);
```

Maybe you need to check if the `HasValue` property is `true` before you use the value. For more examples: http://alexonasp.net/samples/stringformatting/

Answer (score 0):

String.Format() function with mask.  But can you convert your strings to numbers rather than your numbers to strings, for purposes of the comparison? Does it have to be a regex comparison?

Comment: i need a regex for check if there are only two internal decimal places. the float is binding to a text box and in this text box you can use dots or commas

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string s = yourFloat.ToString();
```

Using the invariant culture is recommended if you want to be sure that your output will be in the correct form, but I'd be surprised if there were a culture which doesn't output a comma *or* a dot.

I would also suggest *not* using regular expressions to validate the value of a float.

Comment: I tried this and it doesnt work. What should I take to validate a float?

Comment: @holzleube: If the code I posted prints "12" that's probably because the value of the float *is* actually 12, and not 1.2 like you think it is. How to validate a float depends on what sort of validation you need.

Comment: +1. No idea why it had a -1. Would you consider to be a private beta user on Materials? https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=ZjcxNmMxZjA3ZGFkNWJiMjRhZGQxNjAzY2E0ZTAxYzYzOTc2Yjk4YTFiYWVlZDA2YjlmYWI3NTE0OTNmOGI3OBKIibVWqhq0HqTbmyaNJVtUCXoNz7CCexf2SvvYcVjQ0 It's for the design of new materials: solar cells, photovoltaics, bio-materials, organic LEDs for smartphone screens, new materials for better batteries, energy storage materials, molecular magnets, energy conversion materials, stronger and lighter materials for cars, bikes, planes, spaceships, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that the textbox allows both "." and "," as a decimal-separator (as opposed to a grouping character, also known as a thousands-separator)?

When you are certain that you only get decimal separators and no grouping characters, replace any "," with a "." before using TryParse with an InvariantCulture to convert the string to a float.
OR use the same culture in the code as on the client side, so both will use the same decimal separators.

As others mentioned, a float doesn't have the concept of various decimal separators.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a WinForm Application, there's a static variable `Application.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator`.

Depending on it's value you get different results when converting `ToString()`.
Try manipulating this parameter to achieve necessary result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the problem. I did in my xaml a converter which only allows to enter values with commas as separator, so I dont need any checks if there are only two internal decimal places. Thanks for your help